Postgresql 16: streaming replication - 00000002.history: not found on secondary replica
I'm new to postgres.
Attempting to setup HA - streaming replication.
postgresql.conf are similar on both primary and secondary.
all the params in the conf files seems to be okay.
archive_mode = on
max_wal_senders = 10
archive_command = 'test ! -f /var/lib/postgresql/pg_archive/%f && cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/pg_archive/%f'
primary_conninfo =configured
restore_command ='/var/lib/postgresql/pg_archive/%f "%p"'
exception on the secondary after the below command and start of the replica
pg_basebackup -h x.x.x.x -p 5432 -U replicator -D /var/lib/postgresql/16/pgdata/ -Fp -Xs -R -v
2024-09-26 21:28:17.387 UTC [7766] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-09-26 21:28:17.398 UTC [7769] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2024-09-26 21:27:48 UTC
sh: 1: /var/lib/postgresql/pg_archive/00000002.history: not found
2024-09-26 21:28:18.623 UTC [7769] FATAL:  could not restore file "00000002.history" from archive: command not found
2024-09-26 21:28:18.627 UTC [7766] LOG:  startup process (PID 7769) exited with exit code 1
2024-09-26 21:28:18.627 UTC [7766] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2024-09-26 21:28:18.629 UTC [7766] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
what do I miss?
there is no file /var/lib/postgresql/pg_archive/00000002.history
Thanks in advance!
